# Storing Visualizations and Analysis in Database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, relational-database, visualization

I am currently working on a web-application that would allow users to analyze & visualize data. For example, one of the use-cases is that the user will perform a Principal Component Analysis and store it. There can be other such analysis like a volcano plot, heatmap etc.

I would like to store these analysis and visualizations in a database in the back-end. The challenge that I am facing is how to design a relational database schema which will do this efficiently. Here are some of my concerns:

- The data associated with the project will already be stored in a normalized manner so that it can be recalled. I would not like to store it again with the visualization.
- At the same time, the user should be able to see what is the original data behind a visualization. For eg. what data was fed to a PCA algorithm? The user might not use all the data associated with the project for the PCA. He/she could just be doing this on a subset of the data in the project.
- The number of visualizations associated with the webapp will grow with time. If I need to design an invoved schema everytime a new visualization is added, it could make overall development slower.

With these in mind, I am wondering if I should try to solve this with a relational database like MySQL at all. Or should I look at MongoDB? More generally, how do I think about this problem? I tried looking for some blogs/tutorials online but couldn't find much that was useful.

Comment: Please do not **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/312532

Answer (score 2):

The first step you should do before thinking about technical design, including a relational or non-SQL platform, is a data model that clearly describes the structure and relations between your data in a platform independent way. I see the following interesting points to solve there:

- How is a visualisation related to the data objects it visualizes? When the visualisation just displays the data of one object type (let's say the number of sales per month), this is trivial. But if it covers more than one object type (the number of sales per month, product category, and country), you will have to decide to which of them to link it. There is no single correct solution for this, but it depends on the requirements from the users' view: From which origins will they come to find this visualisation? If they always come from the same origin (let's say the country), it will be enough to link the visuals to that object type.
- How will you handle insertions, deletes, and updates of the basic data since the point in time the visualisation has been generated? If no such operations relevant to the visuals are possible, then it's easy: Just store the selection criteria (country = "Austria", product category = "Toys") with the visual, and everyone will know its meaning. If, however, the basic data can be changed, you should implement a data model that covers historizing those data, i.e. being able to reconstruct the data values on which the original visual was based. Of course, before deciding on this, you need to clarify the requirements: Will, in case of changed basic data, the original visual still be of interest or will it need to be re-generated to reflect the changes?

Both questions are neither simplified nor complicated by using a NOSQL database.

No matter what the outcome of those requirements and data modeling efforts are, I would stick to the following principles:

- Separate the visuals from the basic data, even if a visual is closely related to just one set of basic data. Reason: The visuals are just a consequence of the basic data that can be re-calculated in case they get lost. So the requirements e.g. for data backup will be more strict for the basic data than for the visuals.
- Don't store basic data redundantly to show the basis for each single visual. A timestamp logic with each record of basic data, together with the timestamp of the generated visual will serve the same purpose with less effort and storage volume.

Comment: What would be a good day to 'historizing' data? Let's say the base object for storing data is a Project. Should there be different time stamps of the Project entity?
It would be really helpful if you could suggest a method to come up with the model (or an example).

Comment: A `validFrom` and `validTo` attribute per record is sufficient for most cases. The `validTo` is a small redundancy, as it will be the same as the `validFrom` of the record for the next time period, but it will make queries for the state at a particular point in time easier. So to find all projects in their state valid last Christmas (if they already existed), you just query `where 2014-12-25 between dateFrom and dateTo or dateTo is null and dateFrom <= 2014-12-25`, and you are done.